# Fetch data from contract to my front end

Tags: solidity

I have created database in my contract now in frontend I need some reports for admins which I don't wish to show others like daily sales etc. So how can I get this to my frontend without writing function in contract. My contract will be verified.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you show that data in the UI or not. If the data is publicly accessible, someone would figure out how to pull it. But assuming the data is not that critical, you could possibly build an Admin UI and setup some basic ACL to access it (e.g., username/password or checking metamask ETH address).

Comment: Don't know what ACL is or how to code it in my frontend. Need to find it out.

Comment: just a basic UI with your own defined access rules so that only account satisfying those rules will have access.

Comment: Can you please post some links or example

Comment: You should describe your question in detail and provide some references. I don't know how to answer you.

Comment: @zmy I am storing user data like personal details, their payment details using contract. Now in admin panel I need to show some reports like datewise user join report or datewise payment collection. So I don't want to write any open function to fetch such data. I think there should be any other way to interact with data directly from frontend.

Comment: According to your description, the data in your contract should not be public, so no one else can read it directly. You should write a get function that only you can call to return the data.

Comment: If you don't code the contract, no one can see the data

Comment: My contract is verified so everyone can see it. I wonder if we can call Directly data from blockchain to frontend without writing function in contract or if there is any other way. The goal is not write function in contract.

Comment: You can get the data directly from the blockchain and display it to the front end, but only if the data in your contract is public, or a function has been provided to query the data. Otherwise, you can't get the data.

Comment: Since your contract has been verified and everyone can see it, why don't you send it out and I'll take a look at it for you.

Comment: Can you please provide any example?